# How do I see what files git is configured to ignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I know that I can use the following command to configure git to globally ignore stuff.

```
git config --global core.excludesfile {somefile_that_has_filename_patterns}
```

How do I see what git is configured to ignore?

Comment: `cat ~/.gitconfig` ? Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because: body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 20

Comment: Please make the "question" into real question :)

Answer (score 1):

The global GIT ignore file should be in your HOME directory (`~/.gitignore`), you can also create a `.gitignore` file for each git repository (`ROOT/.gitignore`).
The files are plain text files so you can look at them with any texteditor.

Comment: What if the global file is not at ~/.gitignore?

Comment: Is there a .gitignore in the project root? More info about gitignore http://gitmanual.org/gitignore.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally the ignore file is called .gitignore and resides in the top level directory for the files being ignored. So if your project has `myproject/src/files/` and a directory `myproject/bin` that's being ignored then ignore file is probably at `myproject/.gitignore`.